# Cloud Pub/Sub to BigQuery through Dataflow SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I Would like to understand the working of *Dataflow* pipeline.

In my case, I have something published to cloud pub/sub periodically which *Dataflow* then writes to *BigQuery*. The volume of messages that come through are in the thousands so my publisher client has a batch setting for `1000` messages, 1 MB and `10` sec of latency.

The question is: When published in a batch as stated above, Does *Dataflow SQL* take in the messages in the batch and writes it to BigQuery all in one go? or, Does it writes one message at a time?

On the other hand, Is there any benefit of one over the other?

Please comment if any other details required. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataflow SQL is just a way to define, with SQL syntax, an Apache Beam pipeline, and to run it on Dataflow.

Because it's PubSub, it's a streaming pipeline that is created based on your SQL definition. When you run your SQL command, a Dataflow job starts and wait the messages from pubSub.

If you publish a bunch of messages, Dataflow is able to scale up to process them as soon as possible.

Keep in ming that Dataflow streaming never scale to 0 and therefore you will always pay for 1 or more VM to keep your pipeline up and running.

Comment: So from the point of view of Dataflow pipeline there shouldn't be any material difference whether the messages are published one at a time or in a batch?

Comment: No difference, it's a streaming pipeline that is started and that listen your PubSub.